# HTML 'td' width and height

Tags: html, object, html-table

The 'height' and 'width' are not supported in HTML5. How can I set a td's width and height while conforming to the HTML5 standard?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>219 班網</title>
  </head>

  <body bgcolor="silver">
    <div align="center">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td width="1000" height="250">
            <object width="100%" height="100%" data="frameTop.html"></object>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td width="300" height="700" >
            <object width="100%" height="100%" data="frameLeft.html"></object>
          </td>
          <td width="700" height="700">
            <object width="100%" height="100%" data="frameRight.html"></object>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: To any HTML/javascript people that the code is in C-style layout LOL

Comment: @Zyga So if I use CSS to assign width and height value, it won't be in conflict with HTNL5 standard?

Comment: Thats right, there is no conflict as its CSS code not HTML. The HTML attributes were deprecated in HTML5, nothing to do with CSS if you know what I mean.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

The width attribute of `<td>` is deprecated in HTML 5.

Use CSS.
e.g.

```
 <td style="width:100px">
```

in detail, like this:

```
<table >
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="width:70%">January</td>
    <td style="width:30%">$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What if you need to exceed the width of the page?  For example the width of the page is 2000 and your cell needs to be 5000 like:

          <td style="width:5000px">January</td>

Comment: @IgorKrupitsky put the table inside t div that has css: overflow-x: scroll;
You will then get a horizontal scrollbar

Comment: doesn't seem to work for a table with more columns, and where the columns have varying amounts of data in them

Comment: *"The width attribute of <td> is deprecated in HTML 5."* - it was actually already deprecated in HTML *4*; see https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#edef-TH.

Comment: Its deprecated but I noticed it still working - at least in Chrome 64. Why?

Answer (score 16):

Following [width](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-width.asp) worked well in HTML5: -

```
<table >
  <tr>
    <th style="min-width:120px">Month</th>
    <th style="min-width:60px">Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Please note that

- TD tag is without CSS style.