# Why two tables cannot align properly?

Tags: html

I was maintaining a very old web project and found issues with the alignment. It seems to be very simple HTML or CSS issues, but I couldn't figure it out.

The app generates two tables in the code behind(populates the contents of the second table) and stacks them up like this:

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td width="70%" align="center">Description</td>
    <td width='75px'>Header1</td>
    <td width='75px'>Header2</td>
    <td width='75px'>Header3</td>
  </tr>

</table>

<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td width='70%'>
      <input type="text" name="first_name" value="Software" style="width:100%" />
    </td>
    <td width='75px'>
      <input type="text" value="2000" style="width:100%" />
    </td>
    <td width='75px'>
      <input type="text" value="1" style="width:100%" />
    </td>
    <td width='75px'>
      <input type="text" value="2" style="width:100%" />
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

The first table serves as the header while the second table contains the detail rows.So each header should align properly with its content. But when I resize the window, the alignment is messed up.

I just wondering why it happens as the tables follow the same structure. The only difference is the second table uses some input elements instead of plain text.

Comment: Can't you modify the app to generate one table with the header included ?

Comment: The issue is that the first table's cell widths won't resize smaller than the single text words inside of them. If you **must** use tables, simply add a second row to the first table which contains the inputs: https://jsfiddle.net/saqfnfzs/

Answer (score 0):

That's how tables work. The content of the first table is too big to shrink the table cells as much as the 2nd table. A quick check is to change the text in the first table, see this fiddle for instance: https://jsfiddle.net/q4zzvcra/

Also, `td width="75px"` needs to be `td width="75"` ditch the px

In html 5 width is not supported anymore for `td`, use css instead, see this post: [HTML 'td' width and height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12881067/html-td-width-and-height)

Answer (score 0):

I tried this out at https://jsfiddle.net/9p37p2en/.

> The only difference is the second table uses some input elements instead of plain text.

And that's exactly your problem. The text nodes will never shrink beyond the minimum width of the longest word, so unless you get rid of the overflow in your table, your table cell won't shrink smaller than that. An text INPUT field however can shrink until just a few px.

Also:

- Absolute widths in table cells are ignored if in that same table there are cells with relative width. You can safely remove the `width=75px`, it doesn't do anything at all.
- You should not use `td`'s `width` and `align` properties. Use its style or class property instead together with the correct CSS.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I believe the goal is to keep the width fixed (75px) of header1, header2 and header3 while allowing the Description fill the rest of the screen.